# How to push newly created tag using Lib2Gitsharp

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

Could anybody help me to push the newly created tag using Lib2GitSharp? Below code creates tag correctly, but when I push the tag it gives me "Request failed with statis code: 401"

```
    public static bool createTag(string tag,string localRepoPath)
    {
        var repo = new Repository(localRepoPath);
        if (repo == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "No repository exists in " + localRepoPath);
            return false;
        }
        Tag t = repo.ApplyTag(tag);
        if (t == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "Could not create tag :" + tag);
            return false;
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "Tag has been created successfully :" + tag);
        return true;
    }

    //push the tags
    public static bool pushTags(string tag, string localRepoPath)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Repository repo = new Repository(localRepoPath))
            {
                Remote remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];
                repo.Network.Push(remote, "refs/tags/test1", "refs/tags/test1");

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "----#Errors in push tag " + tag + " " + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Status code 401 means [Unauthorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error). Do you have write perms to that remote repo? Passing the proper creds?

Comment: I was not passing the creds. after doing so got rid of 401 error. Thanks RobertN it helped.

Answer (score 3):

This code works!

```
    public static bool createTag(string tag,string localRepoPath)
    {
        var repo = new Repository(localRepoPath);
        if (repo == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "No repository exists in " + localRepoPath);
            return false;
        }
        Tag t = repo.ApplyTag(tag);
        if (t == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "Could not create tag :" + tag);
            return false;
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "Tag has been created successfully :" + tag);
        return true;
    }

    //push the tags
    public static bool pushTags(string tag, string localRepoPath)
    {
        try
        {
            Credentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials()
            {
                Username = USERNAME,
                Password = PASSWORD
            };
            CredentialsHandler ccd = (url, usernameFromUrl, types) => creds;
            PushOptions options = new PushOptions { CredentialsProvider = ccd };
            string rfspec = "refs/tags/" + tag;
            using (Repository repo = new Repository(localRepoPath))
            {
                Remote remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];
                repo.Network.Push(remote, rfspec, rfspec, options);

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "----#Errors in Push tag " + tag + " " + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```